# anchor tag with absolutely positioned element causes the background image to move on hover in Chrome

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, css-position, absolute

I have an anchor tag with an image and an absolutely position span tag which appears on hover. The problem is that when the anchor tag is hovered over and the span is shown, the image in the anchor tag moves slightly in Google Chrome. All other browsers it works fine.

The HTML is:

```
<a href="{{link}}">
    <span></span>
    <img src="{{image}}" />
</a>
```

The CSS is:

```
#instafeed a {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#instafeed a > span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#instafeed a:hover > span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

How can I stop the image from moving/resizing in Chrome?

You can see the problem here: http://dev.aaronpitts.ch/cj/ (the photos on the left hand side).

Many thanks

Comment: works fine for me, chrome 32

Comment: fine here too - Version 32.0.1700.102 m

Comment: Are you using Mac or Windows? I'm using Chrome 32.0.1700.102 on Mac with the problem. It's mainly the images in the bottom left hand corner that are jumping.

Comment: I don't see it, but you could try setting the text-decoration property explicitly. Perhaps the system is making room for the underline on hover for some reason. (Do you have a custom skin installed on your browser?)